# How to define new fully-functional math brackets in Latex?

Tags: brackets, delimiters

How do I create mathematics paired delimiters such as $()$ or $\langle \rangle$ that satisfy all the functionality of those standard delimiters (by which I mean fully functional)?

In particular, I want those delimiters to work well with `\left \right` and with `\big \bigg \Big ...`.

I have not found any documentation for this.

Comment: it is a feature of the font, similar to f f  becoming an ff ligature

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please explain

Comment: you can not define it from tex, how you define stretchy characters in a font depends on what kind of font it is, opentype or metafont